# How to check social networking authentication in Windows Phone 8 Application?

Tags: c#, authentication, windows-phone-8, social-networking

In my application users can login using the social networks such as facebook, twitter, linkedin so can  any one tell me how to check whether user is already logged in with the facebook/twitter/linkedin in Phone with browser or other internal Apps, My application should also be able to know that the user has logged in so that it should not ask again for the login screen, Even if the user logged in using web browser/Facebook internal App my application should be able to access those credentials and it should allow users to login with out asking for the credentials again.

How to do this.

Thank you for all hints and your help in advance!

Comment: Have you ever seen a WP8 app doing this?

Comment: @PrasannaAarthi In Android this type of behavior is there but i want to know is it possible to implement the same in WP8?

Comment: I dont think its possible with WP..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you ever gone any authentication methods? This [link](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Facebook_authentication_in_Windows_Phone_application) helps you to undergo Facebook login authentication, where it asks for the permission for the first time and if user accepts, it stores all those credentials about the particular user.

Next time the person logs in, they don't want to login again. You just call the login method in startup and it automatically makes the login successful. You can also get the user informations, such as email address and basic informations and store it in your application(Isolated Storage) if the user gives access to your application and you can use it next time when the user enter into the application.

Like you can also perform authentication in Microsoft Account, Facebook, Twitter & Google w/ Mobile Services in the below link

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/WP-Authenticate-Account-c7e0ef84

Comment: I already gone through these things, My question is If in any Other App/Browser/Facebook App etc in User Mobile, If user has logged in then in my application again it should not ask for the log in it should accept & allow the access to the user to log in to the application.

Comment: this link gives solution to your query. http://bsubramanyamraju.blogspot.in/2014/03/direct-facebook-login-support-available.html

Comment: Actually your code is perfectly accepting from a facebook internal app, But how to access the same from the browser can you please explain.

Comment: One thing is that if there is no Facebook internal app in mobile you are displaying a message box that "Search for app in the store?" i just want to know where did you wrote that in the code and it should not do the same it has to check if the user is logged in using browser or not if not then only it should ask for the credentials i.e, Login screen if already logged in browser, App should be authenticated how to check this condition.

Comment: @Krrish Its not like that. "Search for app in the store" is the default function and your write that code when you click login button. 
FacebookSessionClient fb = new FacebookSessionClient(AppId);
            fb.LoginWithApp("public_profile", "custom_state_string"); This two lines automatically invokes that function and it opens default facebook application. Also have look at this link, it uses web browser to perform the task.
http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Facebook_authentication_in_Windows_Phone_application